# System's temp path differs from the fact, whether it's called in a queue or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

I got a really strange problem:

I got a service class, which is called within a queued job. This queued job is being chained and dispatched from an action class.

Inside this action class, `sys_get_temp_dir()` is returning `/var/tmp`.

On the queued job however, the path returned by `sys_get_temp_dir()` is `/var/folders/7s/jq24sk81665c1j4y3v9l3vth0000gn/T`

```
public function doSomething(array $command)
{
    ray(sys_get_temp_dir())->label('methodCall');
}
```

returns `/var/folders/7s/jq24sk81665c1j4y3v9l3vth0000gn/T`.

And to get things even weirder: This is only true if I use the queue (in my case laravel/horizon). PestPHP-tests or manual tests using Tinker(well) do not reproduce the error.

### Attempts to solve the problem

The first thing that comes to mind is that there are different php configurations in place. So I checked the horizon's long-living PHP processes:

```
ahoi             56472   0.0  0.2 410189312  81696 s002  S+    9:20AM   0:00.71 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/bin/php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=macbook-pro-IFR4:supervisor-1 --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=provisioning --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=1 --rest=0
ahoi             56468   0.0  0.1 409899840  54432 s002  S+    9:20AM   0:00.27 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/bin/php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=macbook-pro-IFR4:supervisor-1 --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=deploying --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=1 --rest=0
ahoi             56464   0.0  0.1 409645888  54064 s002  S+    9:20AM   0:00.26 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/bin/php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=macbook-pro-IFR4:supervisor-1 --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=building --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=1 --rest=0
ahoi             56460   0.0  0.1 409629504  53872 s002  S+    9:20AM   0:00.26 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/bin/php artisan horizon:work redis --name=default --supervisor=macbook-pro-IFR4:supervisor-1 --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=default --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=1 --rest=0
ahoi             56433   0.0  0.1 408944448  52160 s002  S+    9:20AM   0:00.47 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/bin/php artisan horizon:supervisor macbook-pro-IFR4:supervisor-1 redis --workers-name=default --balance=auto --max-processes=20 --min-processes=1 --nice=0 --balance-cooldown=3 --balance-max-shift=1 --parent-id=56417 --auto-scaling-strategy=time --backoff=0 --max-time=0 --max-jobs=0 --memory=128 --queue=default,building,deploying,provisioning --sleep=3 --timeout=60 --tries=1 --rest=0
```

This is not the same as I am using in CLI mode:

```
which php
/opt/homebrew/bin/php

ls -lah /opt/homebrew/bin/php
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ahoi  admin    27B Dec 22 12:51 /opt/homebrew/bin/php -> ../Cellar/php/8.3.1/bin/php
```

But:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.3.0/bin/php -r 'echo sys_get_temp_dir();'
/var/folders/7s/jq24sk81665c1j4y3v9l3vth0000gn/T%     

php -r 'echo sys_get_temp_dir();'
/var/folders/7s/jq24sk81665c1j4y3v9l3vth0000gn/T%
```

Both versions are giving the correct path.

Next step is to determine the presence of the TMPDIR environment variable:

Inside the action class, which returns `/var/tmp`:

```
ray(sys_get_temp_dir(), getenv('TMPDIR'))->label('run');
ray()->phpinfo();
```

Here, `getenv('TMPDIR')` returns `false`.

But inside the job processed by horizon

```
ray(getenv('TMPDIR'))->label('run');
```

returns the correct path.

Digging deeper: The problem only appears, if I call the function using an HTTP request. And there, only if the HTTP request is processed by laravel valet.

Using the built-in laravel webserver, `sys_get_temp_dir()`  does return the correct path.

Comment: Are these two scenarios using different PHP configurations? The value can be set/overwritten via the `sys_temp_dir` config setting - but the context for that is PHP_INI_SYSTEM, so it can only happen via php.ini or httpd.conf, but not changed dynamically at runtime.

Comment: I extended my initial question. Actually they are running different versions, but still: The problem only exists, if I call `sys_get_temp_dir()` in the constructor. If I call it in a method, the result is as expected.

Comment: I corrected my initial question again, because the path differs not only if called in the constructor, but also on the action class that actually constructs the class.